# Direct url for an iframe

Tags: php, html, iframe

My company has a local website in which many link buttons are provided in the index.php page and all of the links are opened on iframe within the index page.On opening the index page the iframe is loaded with the 'home.php' page.
I need to give the url of a childpage(sales.php). But on loading its url (www.example.com/sales.php) it opens the sales page alone. I wish to give the url which can open the main page with the 'sales.php' opened in the iframe. Is it possible? Note: I dont have the power make any change in the server.

Pls Help.

Comment: `"I dont have the power make any change in the server."` - You would need to make *some* code change, either in the PHP or in the JavaScript, to make this happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just adapt the php to take a parameter for which page to initially load.

roughly:

```
$pageToLoad = isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:"index";
echo "<iframe src='$pageToLoad.php'></iframe>";
```

then in the calling page open `index.php?page=sales`.

I would add a guard to make sure only pages from a certain list are allowed though.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately you won't be able to do this, it's a limitation of using frames. You can give a link directly to a child page, but it will not be loaded inside the parent frame, so will not look very good!

You will have to give them directions for how to navigate to the page within the website.

***Note:*** Get your company to update that website!!